# Certificate not showing up in certmgr

Tags: ssl-certificate, azure, certificate

Through powershell Cert:\LocalMachine\My certificate store I do see the certificate but through Certificate Manager certmgr.msc I do not see it any where. How do i make it appear there or in IIS Server certificate section. the certificate was imported using the below script.

```
# Install a secret stored in KeyVault into an Azure VM's credential store.
$resourceGroup = [resource group name]
$vm = Get-AzureRmVM -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroup -Name [VM name]
$vaultId = "/subscriptions/[subscription guid]/resourceGroups/$resourceGroup/providers/Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/[vault name]"
$certStore = "My"
$certUrl = [KeyVault secret URL w/ version id]
$vm = Add-AzureRmVMSecret -VM $vm -SourceVaultId $vaultId -CertificateStore $certStore -CertificateUrl $certUrl

# Update the VM so the changes take effect.
Update-AzureRmVM -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroup -VM $vm
```

Comment: when I used the parameter of this form -CertStoreLocation "", it worked.

Answer (score 0):

The steps looks OK, the questions is how was the cert generated. Try generating a Selfsigned cert on your local machine and upload to vault for testing.

```
#Generating self-singed certificate 
$Cert = New-SelfSignedCertificate -Subject "CN=Disk Encryption Cert"  -CertStoreLocation "cert:\LocalMachine\My" -FriendlyName "Disk Encryption Cert" -NotAfter (Get-Date).AddYears(10) -KeyAlgorithm RSA -KeyLength 2048 -Type Custom -KeySpec Signature
Export-PfxCertificate -Cert $cert -Password (ConvertTo-SecureString "Testing123" -AsPlainText -Force) -FilePath .\Diskencrypt.pfx -Force
```

Comment: Did the test certificate work?